# HDRI not appearing as the background

Tags: hdri

[image]I am trying to get an HDRI image load on a small project I am working on. When I go into Shading to set it up, and switch over to Rendered view nothing shows up.
I would really appreciate a solution for this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disable "film > transparent" in the output settings.
[image]